# Run Multiple Spider sequentially

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

```
Class Myspider1
#do something....

Class Myspider2
#do something...
```

The above is the architecture of my spider.py file. and i am trying to run the Myspider1 first and then run the Myspider2 multiples times depend on some conditions. How Could I do that??? any tips?

```
configure_logging()
runner = CrawlerRunner()
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(Myspider1,arg.....)
    yield runner.crawl(Myspider2,arg.....)
crawl()
reactor.run()
```

I am trying to use this way.but have no idea how to run it. Should I run the cmd on the cmd(what commands?) or just run the python file??

thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You just run the python script itself. That's what the classes CrawlerProcess + CrawlerRunner are build for. But please clearify the conditions you talk about. Are these conditions defined before running the script or are these conditions retrieved during/from the run of the first Spider class?

Comment: Thanks for reply, For these two spiders, the first spider Myspider1 is responsible to crawl a series of links, and the second spider Myspider2 is responsible to crawl the links that is missing from the previous links(links was used in Spider1), So I have to run the first spider first and once it closed find whether any urls are missing, and choose to open spider2 or not..

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the `Deferred` object returned by process.crawl(), which allows you to add a callback when the crawl is finished.

Here is my code

```
def start_sequentially(process: CrawlerProcess, crawlers: list):
    print('start crawler {}'.format(crawlers[0].__name__))
    deferred = process.crawl(crawlers[0])
    if len(crawlers) > 1:
        deferred.addCallback(lambda _: start_sequentially(process, crawlers[1:]))

def main():
    crawlers = [Crawler1, Crawler2]
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings=get_project_settings())
    start_sequentially(process, crawlers)
    process.start()
```

The [docs](https://scrapy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process) go into detail about other ways you can run spiders sequentially.

Answer (score 4):

**run the python file**
for example:
**test.py**

```
import scrapy
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your first spider definition
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
               "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print "first spider"

class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your second spider definition
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
                "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print "second spider"

configure_logging()
runner = CrawlerRunner()

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(MySpider1)
    yield runner.crawl(MySpider2)
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run() # the script will block here until the last crawl call is finished
```

Now run **python test.py > output.txt**
You can observe from the output.txt that your spiders run sequentially.

Comment: is it possible to change crawl() to for i in range(1,10): runner.crawl(MySpider,args[i*2]) runner.crawl(MySpider,args[i*2+1) d = runner.join() yield d?  I want to run 2 spiders in parallel, but have them run N times sequentially...

Comment: Well, it did sort of work (my first comment)... the only downside is that it waits for all the "parallel" tasks to finish before executing more "parallel" tasks - and if it often happens that one task is much longer than the others, it effectively becomes sequential rather than parallel...