# Scrapy Crawl multiple spiders subsequently

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I'm a little new to scrapy and I'm stuck at a point. I want to restart a spider when it gets closed.

What I'm trying to implement here is I'm getting URLs from the database I wrote my view in a way that whenever I send a "scrapy crawl xyz" request the start_request will get one URL[next URL] that is different from what was passed in the previous request from the database.

The problem is if there are four URLS in the database I need to run "scrapy crawl xyz" 4 times but I want to avoid that and I am trying to fire "scrapy crawl xyz" when the current "spider_closed" get called at the end of spider. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Multiple Spider sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109400/run-multiple-spider-sequentially)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crawl multiple spiders in one script - you probably want to run the spiders from a script. See [official docummenation on how to do that](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)

To expand on the example provided in the docs, your's should look something like:

```
process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
process.crawl(MySpider2)
process.start()
process.crawl(MySpider3)
process.start()
```

Comment: Thanks Granitosaurus but I don't want to run multiple spider, what i am trying here is to run same spider again when its done scraping data from 1st URL

Comment: In that case you only need to update MySpider.start_urls attribute before adding it to process. By the way why not just pass multiple urls to start_requests when starting the spider?

Comment: While passing multiple URL's together I am getting reset from connection peer and "twisted.python.failure.failure class 'openssl.ssl.error'", but at the same time when I crawling those links one at a time they are getting crawled without any error

Comment: @vrnair How are you passing multiple urls?

Comment: I am passing urls via rest framework i.e. it takes json format data and takes urls from it.....

Comment: " ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method ?.engine_stopped "   This is the error I am getting presently , I was able to call the spider again by using execute command in engine_stopped signal of first instance of scrapy crawl

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I found a problem to my question. I wanted to run same scrapy command simultaneously. so what I did is created my own command in linus and then put my scrapy crawl xyz in a loop and it worked.

## !/bin/bash

for i in `seq 1 3`
do
 scrapy crawl taleo

done