# Scrapy: Run spiders seqential with different settings for each spider

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

For quite a few days now I'm having trouble with **Scrapy**/twisted in my Main.py which is supposed to run different spiders and analyze their outputs. Unfortunately, **MySpider2 relies on** the FEED from **MySpider1** and therefore **can only run after MySpider1 is finished.** Furthermore, **MySpider1 and MySpider2 have different settings.** So far, I have not found a solution that lets me run the spiders sequentially with their respective unique settings. I have looked at the Scrapy CrawlerRunner and CrawlerProcess [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html), and experimented with several related stackoverflow questions ([Run Multiple Spider sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109400/run-multiple-spider-sequentially), [Scrapy: how to run two crawlers one after another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408880/scrapy-how-to-run-two-crawlers-one-after-another?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Scrapy run multiple spiders from a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61444819/scrapy-run-multiple-spiders-from-a-script), and others) without success.

Following the documentation on sequential spiders, my (slightly adapted) code would be:

```
from MySpider1.myspider1.spiders.myspider1 import MySpider1
from MySpider2.myspider2.spiders.myspider2 import MySpider2
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner

spider_settings = [{
    'FEED_URI':'abc.csv',
    'LOG_FILE' :'abc/log.log'
    #MORE settings are here
    },{
    'FEED_URI' : '123.csv',
    'LOG_FILE' :'123/log.log'
    #MORE settings are here
    }]

spiders = [MySpider1, MySpider2]

process = CrawlerRunner(spider_settings[0])
process = CrawlerRunner(spider_settings[1]) #Not sure if this is how its supposed to be used for
#multiple settings but passing this line before "yield process.crawl(spiders[1])" also results in an error.

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield process.crawl(spiders[0])
    yield process.crawl(spiders[1])
    reactor.stop()
crawl()
reactor.run()
```

However, with this code, only the first spider gets executed and without any settings. Therefore, I have tried to use CrawlerProcess with a little more effect:

```
from MySpider1.myspider1.spiders.myspider1 import MySpider1
from MySpider2.myspider2.spiders.myspider2 import MySpider2
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner

spider_settings = [{
    'FEED_URI':'abc.csv',
    'LOG_FILE' :'abc/log.log'
    #MORE settings are here
    },{
    'FEED_URI' : '123.csv',
    'LOG_FILE' :'123/log.log'
    #MORE settings are here
    }]

spiders = [MySpider1, MySpider2]

process = CrawlerProcess(spider_settings[0])
process = CrawlerProcess(spider_settings[1])

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield process.crawl(spiders[0])
    yield process.crawl(spiders[1])
    reactor.stop()
crawl()
reactor.run()
```

This code executes both spiders but simultaneously and not sequentially as intended. Furthermore, it also overwrites the settings of spider[0] with the ones of spider[1] after a second causing the log file to be cut off after only two lines and resumed for both spiders at 123/log.log.

In a perfect world my snippet would work as follows:

1. Run spider[0] with spider_settings[0]
2. Wait until spider[0] is finished.
3. Run spider[1] with spider_settings[1]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate the runners and it should work

```py
process_1 = CrawlerRunner(spider_settings[0])
process_2 = CrawlerRunner(spider_settings[1])

#...

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield process_1.crawl(spiders[0])
    yield process_2.crawl(spiders[1])
    reactor.stop()

#...
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and help! I should have thought of this easy fix myself... Code works fine now.